# Attempting to link a native module using electron-webpack

Tags: webpack, electron-builder, native-module

I wrote a native module in c++ using the v8.h headers and I want to import it in my electron app.

The module works fine. I compile it in it's own folder, then I copy-paste the .node into this boilerplate https://github.com/szwacz/electron-boilerplate and I require it using the `bindings` package.

I would like to use this https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-webpack-quick-start as a starting point to build my electron application. Mainly for two reasons: it is the recommended way and it promises to package your app for macos, linux and windows. I copied the folder containing the source code inside the root folder of the project, I added the `bindings.gyp` file and   `"nodeGypRebuild": "true",` to the `package.json` in the root folder. The module is compiled with `yarn install` but if I try to import it `import {Module} from 'MyModule'` in `src/main/index.js` and run `yarn dev` the output is

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'MyModule' in '/Users/BiA/Src/WebPack/src/main'
```

While googling the problem I landed here https://github.com/chentsulin/electron-react-boilerplate/wiki/Module-Structure----Two-package.json-Structure and now I am even more confused, since there is no `app/` folder in `electron-webpack-quick-start`

Can someone help me finding a way to exit from this dead end? Does it exist a documentation that covers this case? Even a working example, like an open source project where I can lear to do this would help.

edit: to better understand the problem I created a simple git repository: https://github.com/BiancoA/electron-webpack-quick-start-nm

Comment: Why do you use two package.json? In `electron-webpack-quick-start` you should put your files in the `src` folder

Comment: @kontrollanten thanks for the comment. Do you mean that I should also put the code of my module?

Comment: Hard to say. Do you have a file called MyModule in `/Users/BiA/Src/WebPack/src/main`?

Comment: I can copy (binding.gyp allows you to do that) the MyModule.node file into `/Users/BiA/Src/WebPack/src/main`, but this does not solve the problem

Comment: Okey. It would be helpful if you can show some code showing how you're importing and trying to use the module

Comment: ok, tomorrow I will try to add a minimal working example

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157584/discussion-between-bia-and-kontrollanten).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to the problem using `yarn link`: https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/link/

here I saved the working project:
https://github.com/BiancoA/electron-webpack-quick-start-nm

If there are other possible ways, I'll be happy to learn them